# Invoke a aws lambda function using MWAA DAG and schedule it for 15 minutes

Tags: python, aws-lambda, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, mwaa

Invoke a aws lambda function using MWAA DAG and schedule it for 15 minutes

Tried and followed below solution but it didnt work

[Python/Airflow AttributeError: 'AwsLambdaHook' object has no attribute 'update_relative'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72356638/python-airflow-attributeerror-awslambdahook-object-has-no-attribute-update-r)

Error is "DAG Import Error"

Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/invoke_lambda_dag.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/invoke_lambda_dag.py", line 6, in 
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.aws_lambda import AwsLambdaInvokeFunctionOperator
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.aws_lambda'

Referred below documentation as well

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/_api/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/operators/lambda_function/index.html#airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.lambda_function.LambdaInvokeFunctionOperator

Below is the code:

import json, boto3
from airflow import DAG, utils
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator, BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.lambda_function import (
LambdaCreateFunctionOperator,
LambdaInvokeFunctionOperator,
)

DAG_ID = "InvokeLambda"

with DAG(
DAG_ID,
schedule="*/15 * * * *",
start_date=datetime(2023, 11, 24),
tags=["example"],
catchup=False,
) as dag:

```
lambda_function_name = "lambda_name"

invoke_lambda_function = LambdaInvokeFunctionOperator(
    task_id="invoke_lambda_function",
    function_name=lambda_function_name,
    payload=None,
)
```

invoke_lambda_function

It is working but the problem here is , the aws lambda is triggering twice with a gap of 1 min in 15min schedule.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBo7f.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.